# How to make Eclipse CDT code formatter understand rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting, rvalue-reference

I have a rather annoying issue with Eclipse CDT IDE code formatter / parser and I cannot find answer to it.

For some reason, IDE parser does not treat rvalue reference as part of normal C++ code and, upon encountering it, breaks the code formatting with all the consequences of Indexer starting to misbehave, code highlighting and formatting going crazy. It's just IDE issue, but it's very annoying - I have to define a C-style macro that expands to `&&` to workaround it.

From the fact that I cannot find any information on it, I assume, I'm one of a few unlucky ones who have such issue. Maybe, someone knows what I need to tweak to get it to work? I'm Using Eclipse Indigo CDT x64 for Win7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a duplicate of: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389235

Eclipse CDT has known about rvalue references for a while, as seen in attachment 152935 of this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294730 But I guess that knowledge must be limited to whatever Eclipse CDT does *other than* "be a syntax-highlighting editor."

In general, if you have a bug report about a specific piece of open-source software, the right place to ask for help is on the Bugzilla (or whatever bug tracker) for that specific piece of software.